# Having problems in Selenium example code java

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, manjaro

[First Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoO4p.png)

[Second Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3wQW.png)

I am running the selenium example code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated;
import java.time.Duration;

public class HelloSelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        try {
            driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
            driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
            WebElement firstResult = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3>div")));
            System.out.println(firstResult.getAttribute("textContent"));
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

And getting the errors as shown in the screenshots above.

Note that the action is being performed but the last statement in the *try* block isn't printing the attribute of the firstElement. I understand the problem is not very easy to read but solving should be interesting.

Also I am using the geckodriver (for Firefox) in Manjaro.

And I am using gradle.

Comment: You should copy/paste the output here directly instead of posting screenshots. The error says that the `wait()` never finds an element matching the given CSS selector. You need to figure out why the element isn't there when you expect it to be. I usually debug these kinds of issues in my IDE by setting a breakpoint and stepping through the test. Be sure that you configure the web driver to open a browser so you can see it. In other words, don't run your tests headless when you are debugging.

Comment: The web driver is configured to open a browser. And the error is shown even after both of the WebElement lines are commented out.

Comment: Sorry, the presenceOfElementLocated() error goes away. What is the part other than that? I mean the presenceOfElementLocated() bit is small. What about other errors?

Answer (score 1):

It states the error on the debug window.

```
 WebElement firstResult = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h3>div")));
```

An exception is thrown because there is a timeout on the "wait.until" function.

It doesn't find the element you are searching for.

Your css selector is invalid.

Comment: "Your css selector is invalid." Or the page the OP is expecting hasn't loaded

Comment: The error shows even after the line is commented out :(

Comment: Sorry, the presenceOfElementLocated() error goes away. What is the part other than that? I mean the presenceOfElementLocated() bit is small. What about other errors?

Comment: Other errors are engine errors, nothing you can do about.